# Async WebAPI Controller serving images - Pending HTTP Requests

Tags: c#, image, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently playing around with an async WebAPI controller that serves images and I'm facing a strange behaviour.

The short scenario is: 
The Controller gets an Image by ID and loads it via EF6 from the database.
The blobresult contains the filename, contentType and the data as byte[].
I have a small image gallery with potentially +100 that points to the controller via standard img tag like this:

```
<img src="//path/to/webapicontroller/1" />
```

This is more or less the complete code:

```
public class BlobImageController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(Guid id, [FromUri]int width, [FromUri]int height)
    {
        var service = new BlobService();

        // pull stuff via EF from database using async EF APIs
        var blobResult = await service.ReadAsync(id);

        string contentType = blobResult.ContentType;

        var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(blobResult.Filename);

        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        var stream = new MemoryStream(blobREsult.content);

        stream.Position = 0;
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;

        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
        return result;
    }
}
```

The Problem:
The previous synchronos controller served this well, but with this async version the browser only downloads the first 7-10 images and all other requests are pending. On the server side is no load - it's stuck somewhere.
If I use another browser it works with the first 7 as well and I receive only 7 requests on the server side.

When I look at the Chrome Dev Tools the outstanding requests are all pending, while the successfull requests are "OK".

This also happens if I use a ByteArrayContent. Both versions are working well with the synchronos version.

What do I miss?

Comment: Are you on .NET 4.5 and have `targetFramework` set to `4.5` in your web.config?

Comment: Yes - targetFramework="4.5" in config & project. The webapp even relies on some .NET 4.5 assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

Found it: I also used the Glimpse ASP.NET MVC Package. When I remove the Glimpse Module from the system.WebServer configuration then everything works as expected.

I did the testing with this packages:

```
 <package id="Glimpse" version="1.8.2" targetFramework="net45" />
 <package id="Glimpse.AspNet" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net45" />
 <package id="Glimpse.Mvc5" version="1.5.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

I opened a issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/797